# PostgreSQL: Error importing csv file from shared network folder

Tags: postgresql

My goal is to import csv file to postgresql database.
my file is located in network shared folder and I do not have no option to make it in a local folder.
My Folder located in :

```
"smb://file-srv/doc/myfile.csv"
```

When I run my this PostgreSQL script:

```
COPY tbl_data
FROM 'smb://file-srv/doc/myfile.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

I would get this error :

```
ERROR: could not open file "smb://file-srv/doc/myfile.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
SQL state: 58P01
```

I have no problem to access the file and open it.
I am using PostgreSQL 9.6 under Ubuntu 16.04.
Please Advice how to fix this problem.

Update

When I try to access the file with postgres user I would have same error:

```
postgres@file-srv:~$$ cat smb://file-srv/doc/myfile.csv
cat: 'smb://file-srv/doc/myfile.csv' : No such file or directory
```

As I mention when I user mounted folder I created I can access the file.

Answer (score 0):

it is about permission. you have to check read access on file and folders.
also, logging with superuser access may solve your problem.

Comment: I mount the folder and I am able to access it and open the file, also I edit the permission to allow everyone access the file but still I am getting same error

Answer (score 0):

In short, this is a permissions issue: Your network share is likely locally mounted to your *user's* UID, while the PostgreSQL server is running as the `postgres` user.

Second, when you log into your database, there is *not* an overlap between the database's users and the system's users, even if you have the same username.  This means that when you request a file from your network share, the DB user, in this case `postgres`, does not have the necessary permissions.

To see this, and assuming you have `root` access on the box in question, you might try to become the `postgres` user and see that you cannot access the file:

```
$ sudo su - postgres
$ cat /run/user/.../smb.../yourfile.csv
Permission denied
```

The fix to your issue will involve -- somehow -- making the file or share accessible to the `postgres` user.  Copying is certainly the quickest way.  But that's off the table.  You could mount the share (perhaps as read only) as the `postgres` user.  You might do this in fstab.

However, unless this is going to be an automated detail that happens regularly, this seems like heroics.  Without more information as to *why* you can't copy locally, I suggest copying the file locally.

Comment: When I try to access the file with postgres user I would have same error:

postgres@file-srv:~$$ cat smb://file-srv/doc/myfile.csv
cat: 'smb://file-srv/doc/myfile.csv' : No such file or directory  
As I mention when I user mounted folder I created I can access the file.

Comment: @Eyla that's exactly the point.  The database _runs_ as the `postgres` user.  Until you fix the permissions to allow the `postgres` user to access the file, you will have this issue.